# how to colour different Rmarkdown kable tables in different colour

Tags: css, r, knitr, r-markdown

Below is the code I am using. Only problem is that both my tables are of same colour which is my second colour code (#ffff99). How can I keep the background of both tables different.

````
<style>
table {
background-color:#eff8e5;
}
</style>
``` {r}
kable(df1)
```

<style>
table {
background-color:#ffff99;
}
</style>
``` {r}
kable(df2)
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML/CSS is not rendered the way you implicitly assume. Your code would work as expected if the rendering followed a procedure like:

> - set: "tables are green"
> - output green table
> - set: "tables are yellow"
> - output yellow table

But this is not the case. What actually happens is:

> - set: "all tables are green"
> - output table 1
> - (table 1 is green)
> - set: "all tables are yellow"
> - output table 2
> - (table 1 **and** table 2 are yellow)

As a solution, you could use two different classes:

```
<style>
.lightgreen {
  background-color:#eff8e5;
}

.yellow {
  background-color:#ffff99;
}
</style>
```

<sup>(Optimally, class names should describe the *reason* why the class is used and not how the class currently looks like, but without further information "lightgreen" and "yellow" are the best names I came up with).</sup>

Now you need to tell `kable` that the tables should get these classes assigned.

**Option 1:**

```
kable(df1, format = "html", table.attr = "class=\"lightgreen\"")
kable(df2, format = "html", table.attr = "class=\"yellow\"")
```

However, this strips most of the (probably desired) default table layout.

**Option 2:** Add a container around the tables and style tables in that container.

````
<style>
.lightgreen table {
  background-color:#eff8e5;
}

.yellow table {
  background-color:#ffff99;
}
</style>

<div class = "lightgreen">

```{r}
library(knitr)

df1 <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=2:11)
kable(df1)
```

</div>

<div class = "yellow">
```{r}
df2 <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=2:11)
kable(df2)
```

</div>
````