# How to change font size in knitr::kable in Beamer slides?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

In Beamer presentation created using rmarkdown I have a slide with table, e.g.

````
## Slide with table

```{r, asis = TRUE}
dat <- mtcars
knitr::kable(dat)
```
````

How can I control the font size so that the whole table fits the slide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest trying the [kableExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) package.

Otherwise, the easiest way I know of is to specify a CSS class for the table and then define the font size in CSS.  See [how to colour different Rmarkdown kable tables in different colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509219/how-to-colour-different-rmarkdown-kable-tables-in-different-colour)